# Why doesn't `cancelPreviousRequestsWithTarget` cancel an NSTimer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nstimer, performselector

I schedule an `NSTimer` instance like this:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.2 target:self selector:@selector(someMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I am able to call `invalidate` on my `NSTimer` to stop it from firing, but

```
    [NSTimer cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

does not stop the timer. I have checked and `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` is exactly the same (as expected, these are in responses to user clicks) and of course the `self` instance is always the same. Why doesn't `cancel` cancel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` is an NSObject method, not an NSTimer method, and it is the inverse of NSObject's `performSelector:` methods.

`[NSTimer cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]` is the same as `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]`, and what it cancels is any previous `[self performSelector:… withObject:… afterDelay:…]` messages. It has nothing to do with any NSTimer instances.

Sending the message to the NSTimer class rather than the NSObject class works the same way that sending `alloc` to a class does. No classes override it; it works because NSObject's implementation is inherited, and it does the same thing for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I see the confusion. I am scheduling with the wrong method, essentially. Hadn't noticed when or that I'd switched.

Comment: So it seems that for static methods, since Class does not conform to NSObject (I think), NSTimer is the only way to go. Please ignore the obviously bad design that this conveys :)

Comment: The `Class` type says only that the value is a class; it doesn't say anything about what the class does or does not conform to, or is or is not a subclass of. That matters not at run time; what matters at run time is what message you send and which class you send it to. Additionally, classes actually can respond to otherwise-unrecognized class messages using instance methods from the root class (which, in this case, is NSObject). http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-TPXREF120

Comment: All that said, I've found that using an NSTimer and managing it yourself almost always produces cleaner code than delayed performs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, all points noted. Good stuff, especially the note about the root class. I'll use NSTimer though, agreed that the code is much cleaner. It's also easier to track down in global searches :)